# Split commit in history

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase

I'm attempting to learn, how to split commit in history. I use this page to guide me: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase.html#_splitting_commits I have two commits, so I enter the `git rebase -i <hashOfTheCommit>^`. I change the line with the commit from `pick` to `edit`. Then I type `git reset HEAD^`. So far so good. Now, there is the change introduced by the commit consisting of adding a `file1` in new directory.

The content of the file is basically two lines:

```
commit line1

commit line2
```

So I want to split this commit into two commits, each introducing addition of one line. But after I type `git add -p file1`, I get only the response `No changes.` and the file is not added to the index. I would expect being taken into the patch mode, but it doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

If even a git add --interactive doesn't work either, as a guess, it might be because the *all* file is already in the index.

If so, try a:

```
git reset HEAD -- file
git add -p -- file
```

Comment: what do you mean by `all` file? I do not have any file with that name and my `file1` is untracked after the `git reset HEAD^` command

Comment: @coubeatczech "all" = the full content of that file. I presume `git add --interactive` didn't work as well?

Comment: yes, `git add --interactive` doesn't work as well, and the file is definitely not in the index. Sorry for quite late answer, I didn't get notified...

Answer (score 0):

You  may also use the GUI for this task (it cannot be automated as the command line, but maybe it works for your case).

Just make a branch point to the commit you want to split and checkout that branch (let's call this branch *splitcommit*). Open the GUI (`git gui`) and select 'Ammend last commit' (it's above the commit description text box). Once you select that option, you are just in the same situation as if you were creating the commit in question, so you can select the file and stage/unstage the lines you want (select the lines on the box that shows the file contents and click on stage/unstage as you wish).

Once you are ready, click commit. That will modify your commit, and the lines that you unstaged will be shown as changes not added to the index. You can then create a new commit with those lines (it will be added to branch *splitcommit*). If you want to redo the history of your original branch with the new splitted commit, checkout that branch and rebase to branch *splitcommit*.

It's not very straightforward, but it's not a really complex process, no need to use ver advanced Git commands.